# Reactjs Authentication/Authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, authorization

I need to split a reactjs app into 2 pieces and then protect one of them with a  username/password. I've read a couple of tutorials about that. But seems their approach is about to load whole app into web browser and then just show/hide something depending on authentication. What I need is the protected parts must not be passed to the client side (browser) at all. What is the common reactjs practice to do that, please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use server side renderer like Next.js or something to show or hide your application parts based on authorization levels from the server.

I generally use standard html form for login pages and sending the real application only when the user authenticated. For showing or hiding special parts I am trying to split the application into chunks, you can see the details [in this article](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-code-splitting/).

Think about server sider renderers maybe they are what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

My Suggestion is use react-router (react-router-dom) library.

[Follow this sample code example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: I know the react-router approach. But have you read my requirements? ;)